# Getting a WordPress tag to print inside of a traditional php echo

Tags: php, templates, tags

I want to get the template path to print in this echo of a form in the admin.

Here is what I got:

```
< ?php echo of_get_option('splash_img_transition', 'bloginfo('template_url')+/images/large/chalk.jpg' ); ?>
```

The second parameter there is a placeholder if nothing is input into the field that I am echoing.

Normally the echo works like this: `< ?php echo of_get_option('splash_img_transition', 'no entry' ); ?>`

And of course the WP tag `< ?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>`

I'm just trying to combine the two so that the default (if the user does not input anything) will be a path to a placeholder image.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Most Wordpress functions, that generate output, do echo that output by them self. But all those functions are just wrappers for the accordingly get_*-functions.

In your case its [bloginfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) and [get_bloginfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo), where the second returns the output, so you can use it for whatever you like.